# Save our system tags!

Tags: support, tags, game-systems

According to [this meta suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127700/do-not-expire-single-use-tags-that-have-a-tag-wiki), single-use tags will no longer expire **if they have a tag wiki.**

[We have a historic problem](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2726/1204) whereby users will ask about a game system (and a tag will be created for it), but that will be the only question on the system, dooming the tag to later be obliterated and, in a lot of cases, the context for the question will be lost. Help us save them!

## What can you do to help?

Add system tags to the below list that only have one question and no tag wiki. Link its lone question as well, so that in the future the tag can be recreated and reapplied.

Rescue tags on the below list by either proposing a tag wiki, asking another question with that tag, or tagging another question about that system with that tag. If the tag's been destroyed since, add it back to the linked question if and when you can also rescue it through one of those actions.

If any of the below tags ought not exist, remove them from the question so they can be obliterated.

Remove tags from this list when they're safe (or deliberately obliterated). Please note in the edit summary what you did exactly ("created a wiki", "tagged another question", etc). If you've proposed a tag wiki, wait until the tag wiki's approved before removing it.

## Single-question system tags in need of attention

- [the-multiverse-rpg](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-multiverse-rpg) ([Are the rules for ignoring actions and having separate realities in contradiction?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/22653/multiverse-question-on-ignoring-actions))
- [rotworld](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rotworld) ([Is there a trick to learning the Pacesetter/Goblinoid Action Table?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/13998/is-there-a-trick-to-learning-the-pacesetter-goblinoid-action-table))
- [mechanical-dream](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mechanical-dream) ([Mechanical Dream rules gathered together](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/12103/mechanical-dream-rules-gathered-together))

Also, quite possibly anything in the [untagged](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag. If a system tag expires and it was the only tag on the question at the time, the question will wind up in [untagged](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged).

Comment: If we don't know enough to write a full wiki, does a tag summary also save it from deletion?

Comment: @Emrakul Tag summaries are never mentioned in that topic, so I'm not sure. That said, you don't have to write a huge amount to make a tag wiki.

Comment: @Emrakul A link to the game's website and a sentence goes a long way.

Comment: The [tag:fasa] tag has survived over six months with no activity as a solo tag. I think that means tag summaries will do?

Comment: I added the info for In Nomine, but it needs to be approved.

Comment: I also added one for human-occupied-landfill.

Comment: I added a tag wiki for Iron Kingdoms, barring a peer review.

Comment: How do you find these tags?  I assume the question can't auto-update...

Comment: @thedarkwanderer We found them through coincidence or searching. There were some [[tag:untagged]] questions we provided with system tags (specifically the three in the question, which have now become untagged again because I got lazy about creating wikis for them), and at one point I went through every tag with only 1 question to find out which ones were system tags which didn't have a wiki.

Comment: @doppelgreener Wow.  That sounds exhausting.  Thanks for doing that.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer Thankfully there were not that many and the work was easy enough. :)

Comment: Wait a second... We are editing questions to add tags back so that the context of a question will not be lost when the tags are vacuumed... Why don't we just edit the questions to add the context back into the question, regardless of tags?  Aren't questions supposed to be able to stand on their own without tags?

Comment: @Tritium21 no, not really.  Also tags are important anyways for filtering.

Comment: @Tritium21 Yes, normally, but system tags are a special case since they're often the only place the system appears (and that's conventionally OK).

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Then lets go ahead and fix the system tag, but while we have the edit window open... add the context into the question itself.

Comment: @Tritium21 Most of these one-question tags already do mention their context in the question. It would be redundant and noisy to artificially add the system context to every question's text though. I believe there is already a meta on that idea, anyway, which concluded "don't do that."